# How to Handing String Values While Performing Linear Regression Using Weka Java API

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, weka, mahout

I am performing Linear Regression using Weka Java API. The data set consists of UserId, URL visited by user, Time spend on Page. As the URL is a String attribute, I am facing problem while performing Linear Regression with above dataset. Is their any ready to use method which converts String to equivalent Int values in Weka. I have seen a similar kind of functionality in Mahout but could not find it in Weka. I can easily create a function to output Int values of the string by calculating the sum of ASCII if each characters, but I want a more reliable and already tested solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that linear regression only operates on numeric values. However, it is not at all true that just any old conversion from categorical values to numbers will be fine. For example, hashing a string gives a number, but would give completely meaningless results as a feature for linear regression.

Numeric values are expected to have an ordering and meaningful magnitude. What would it mean that "foo.com" is 135092 and "bar.com" is 985882? Linear regression would try to interpret "bar.com" as "something like 5 times larger than foo.com" which is nonsense.

You may be thinking of 1-of-n encoding, where you create a new 0/1 feature for every possible value (URL). This won't be feasible for URLs. Domains -- maybe.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can u please suggest any other algorithm wherin I cn make use of my data set to fetch the mostly visited url. My aim is to recommend Products to user based on his visit on an ecommerce site.

Comment: "Fetch the most visited URL" is not a machine learning problem -- it's a SQL query. Neither of these is a recommender problem. You need to dramatically clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: My Appplication keeps track of all online activities of an user within a ecommerce application . Based on that it should perform sentimental analysis of user behaviour and provide recommended offers to user. Ofcourse we can get most visited urls by user, but my application should also be able to recommend products which are similar to those, the user spent more time on

Comment: Our aim is to apply a Regression or similar kind of Algorithm to the collected data and come up with a confident score so that based on the  score values, we can recommend products with say top 5 score values to user.

Answer (score 0):

While Weka LinearRegression classification is not working with String data type, you can try convert all the websites to nominal, which can be calculated by algorithm. I am not too sure how exactly algorithm performs, but in my experience it improved results in some cases (as nominal can be counted as repeating values, distance between values ~1 if not equal etc.).